# How to insert complex object in roomDb

Tags: android, android-room

I have table `MainObject` with this structure:

```java
Data class MainObject {
   List<Object1> object1 = new ArrayList<>();
   List<Object2> object2 = new ArrayList<>();
   Object3 object3;
}

Data class Object1 {
   String name1 = "";
   String name2= "";
   List<Object4> object4 = new ArrayList<>();
}

Data class Object2 {
   String name1 = "";
   String name2= "";
   Int num  = 1
}

Data class Object3 {
   String name1 = "";
   String name2= "";
   List<Object5> object5 = new ArrayList<>();
}

Data class Object4 {
   String name1 = "";
   String name2= "";
   Int num  = 1
}

Data class Object5 {
   String name1 = "";
   String name2= "";
   Int num  = 1
}
```

Now My concern is should I go ahead with relations with many classes or simple write type converters.
For less complex object it is easy to maintain relation. But what should be done in such cases.
I have multiple objects(around 10) in single table to be saved. Will have type converters make my app slow.

Wont writing so many join queries make app slow.

Answer (score 0):

In my development career, at many places I also faced the same problem so my solution to this will be
If you are in development phase and data class may change also **if the data class is complex you should go ahead with type converter**

On the other hand **if it's not complex and relations can be managed easily then go with creating relations** but keep in mind that for future development will relation halt you development process or not.

Comment: here Data class wont change but the data class are too complex as we objects inside objects upto 2 3 layers.

Comment: Go with type converters